# Netbeans not updating files created by ruby script-generators :(

Tags: netbeans-6.9

No matter how long I wait, eventually I have to restart Netbeans 6.9 to be able to see files under projects/files tabs that are created by ruby shell command (externally; as opposed to generation from the option available in Netbeans).

=>"Should I have to switch to VisualStudio2010?".inspect

--Pak1standby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a Source > Scan to have your ide re-sync up with your file system.

Comment: Thanks that helped! can I set it to auto-scan?